# while scrolling, ListView Listview item changes the position.Why?

Tags: java, android, listview

When i am scrolling `ListView` position of the item changes.My `ListView` contain 2 `Button` and 2 `TextView`. These 2 `Button` are initially invisible. when user Long click on item i just set the visibility.Its working but when i scroll the `ListView` ,it changes the position.Why?

I am setting this visibility and invisibility code inside of my adapter class..
here is my code :::

```
  @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.message_row, null);
        holder.messageDeleteButton = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        holder.messageTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.message);
        holder.timeTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.time);
        holder.copyMessageButton = (ImageButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.copy_bt);

        holder.messageDeleteButton
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View v) {

         System.out.println("Delete clicked");
                        }
                });

        convertView.setTag(R.layout.message_row, holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(R.layout.message_row);
    }
    convertView.setTag(position);

    holder.messageDeleteButton.setTag(position);
    if (mMessageData.get(position).isVisible())
        holder.messageDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        holder.messageDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.messageTextView.setText(mMessageData.get(position)
            .getMessage_text());
    holder.messageTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(
            mContext.getAssets(), "Existence-Light.ttf"));
    holder.timeTextView.setText(mMessageData.get(position)
            .getMessage_date());
    holder.timeTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(
            mContext.getAssets(), "Existence-Light.ttf"));
    convertView.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener);
    convertView.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    // convertView.setOnLongClickListener(mLongClick);
    return convertView;
}
```

This is my OnTouchListiner code it will working fine.But when i scroll the `ListView` the buttons positions will changed..

```
      class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
            new GestureListener());

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int touch = 0;
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag(R.layout.message_row);
        animation = new Animater();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        pos = position;
        view = v;
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            action_down_x = (int) event.getX();
            Log.d("action", "ACTION_DOWN - ");
            touch = 0;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.d("action", "ACTION_MOVE - ");
            action_up_x = (int) event.getX();
            difference = action_down_x - action_up_x;
            calcuateDifference(holder, position);
            touch = 1;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d("action", "ACTION_UP - ");
            // calcuateDifference(holder, position);
            action_down_x = 0;
            action_up_x = 0;
            difference = 0;
            // touch = 2;

            break;
        }
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public GestureDetector getGestureDetector() {
        return gestureDetector;
    }
}
```

In this gestuer class when i tap on `ListView` just display one more `Button`.This also be changed the position

```
 public class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener{
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onLongPress(e);


        final ViewHolder hold = (ViewHolder) view.getTag(R.layout.message_row);
        hold.copyMessageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        hold.copyMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                System.out.println("hello you click me..");
        });


    }

}
```

What is the wrong on my code..Any one please help me...

Comment: view holder pattern not properly implemented , your are tagging your view with a position and the view holder. Save the position in the holder instead.

Comment: Please tell me in which line i am doing wrong..and please send me your solution.I am knew for this...

Answer (score 1):

Android `ListView` use Adapters to recycle views that's why `ListView` position changes while scrolling to conserve memory.See the Google I/O presentation given by Romain Guy to understand how adapters work. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA

Also check the below links,

http://strangevikas.wordpress.com/tag/how-adapter-works-in-android-android-and-adapters/

http://www.edureka.in/blog/what-are-adapters-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do some modification in your code like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.message_row, null);
        holder.messageDeleteButton = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        holder.messageTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.message);
        holder.timeTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.time);
        holder.copyMessageButton = (ImageButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.copy_bt);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.messageDeleteButton.setTag(mMessageData.get(position));

    holder.messageDeleteButton
    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {

            // message data can be retrieved here like
            MessageData mData = (MessageData) v.getTag(); 
            System.out.println("Delete clicked");
        }
    });

    if (mMessageData.get(position).isVisible())
        holder.messageDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        holder.messageDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.messageTextView.setText(mMessageData.get(position)
            .getMessage_text());

    holder.messageTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(
            mContext.getAssets(), "Existence-Light.ttf"));
    holder.timeTextView.setText(mMessageData.get(position)
            .getMessage_date());
    holder.timeTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(
            mContext.getAssets(), "Existence-Light.ttf"));

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: when i add your code i am getting classcastexception inside of the ontouch method in int position = (Integer) v.getTag() line..... at com.pctoapp.adapter.MessagesAdapter$MyTouchListener.onTouch(MessagesAdapter.java:171)

Comment: You have made mistake at line int position = (Integer) v.getTag(), You have to cast the data which you previously set in setTag() method. i think its MessageData object. so you can change int position = (Integer) v.getTag() this code by MessageData data = (MessageData) v.getTag() like this.